# How to prevent cron emails when script writes to stdout and stderr

Tags: linux, unix, cron, io-redirection

I have a script, which we will call `script.sh` that writes to both `stdout` and `stderr`.

I want to pipe the output (`stdout`) of this script to `mailx`, but I don't want any email from `cron`.

Here's my crontab, set to 4:00 PM daily:

```
00 16 * * * /path/to/script.sh | mailx name@domain.com >/dev/null 2&>1
```

Via `mailx` I get the script's `stdout` output, but I still get an email from `cron` containing the script's `stderr` output.

I've also tried stripping away `stderr` on the left side of the pipe, as follows:

```
00 16 * * * /path/to/script.sh 2> /dev/null | mailx name@domain.com
```

This results in `cron` sending me an email that says:

```
Null message body; hope that's ok
```

Actually, dear `cron`, that's not okay with me.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

**edit:** Another interesting experiment...

```
00 16 * * * test -d /
```

This has no output whatsoever, yet I get an email from `cron` saying that the message subject and body are empty... so why send it? :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the mail any time the cron command has some output (stdout or stderr). 
The message *"Null message body; hope that's ok"* is a warning from the `mailx` command. The following modification will suppress all the warnings from mailx:

```
00 16 * * * /path/script.sh 2> /dev/null | mailx name@domain.com > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Notes:

1. Be aware that if there is any error sending the email, you will not get *any* report about it.
2. Are you sure the stderr of `script.sh` shouldn't be mailed too? If yes, use `2>&1` instead of `2> /dev/null`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit hacky...but you can set the MAILTO variable to an empty value so that cron is not sending mail at all.

Open the crontab file with:

```
crontab -e
```

and at the top simply prepend:

```
MAILTO=""
```

I don't know if it goes against some of your constraints.

If you want to do it just for your script you may try something like that in your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

OLDMAILTO=$MAILTO

MAILTO=""

# do your stuff here

MAILTO=$OLDMAILTO
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do this. I'm writing a script that installs this on the user's crontab; if (s)he has other entries, I don't want to mess up their MAILTO variable.

Comment: Perfectly understandable. I have done something similar...i'll edit my answer in a while